# How can a HTML button execute a selenium(java) code present in remote location(By Button Click)

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, uibutton, buttonclick

I have a Selenium Code written in Java, Which is present in some NAS(Network Attached Storage) or some connected machine. 
And I want to create a web page which contains a button,
By clicking that button selenium script present in connected machine/nas drive should be executed and the respective logs should be populated in my web page.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Using .bat or .sh file commands

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that will be using Jenkins (or any other CI). It offers a webview of your "projects" where you can start execution build on one click.

Refer [this](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/integration-of-jenkins-with-selenium-webdriver/) link for a basic tutorial on how to do it with a selenium project.